# AsyncBridge.Net35.0.2.0, await task

Tags: .net-3.5, async-await

I'm using the asyncbridge for 3.5, and have run into a problem.
When I have a method returning a void, I know I have to return a Task.

However, the method below doesn't work

```
public async Task PingAsync()
{
  return await Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginPing, client.EndPing, new object());
}
```

Works like a charm when I return values, I.E. return await Task.FromFactory....

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why are you using `async/await` at all if you're just calling a method which returns a task anyway? Remove the `async` and `await` words to start with - you're just adding an extra layer for no real benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you can just change it to:

```
public Task PingAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginPing, client.EndPing, new object());
}
```

There's no benefit in making this an `async` method - you're *just* trying to create a task representing the async operation, and `TaskFactory.FromAsync` does that for you.

If you *really* want to use `async` and `await`, just remove the `return` part:

```
public async Task PingAsync()
{
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginPing, client.EndPing, new object());
}
```

Looking at the overloads for `FromAsync` I suspect you might want `client.BeginPing()` instead of `client.BeginPing`... and it's not clear why you're creating a new `object` as the state instead of just using `null`. Presumably you're not *using* that state...

Comment: Cheers, gold as always from you mister! :) You don't have to await for something that doesn't return anything ofc!

Comment: @stian: I'm not sure I understand your comment... it's more that you can't return a value from an async method returning `Task`. You can `await` the result of `Task.Factory.FromAsync`... but that `await` expression is a void expression, effectively.

Comment: Yes that was what I was trying to say. But another one here:            public async Task SetGridLayoutAsync(GridLayout gridLayout)
        {
          await Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginSetGridLayout, client.EndSetGridLayout, gridLayout, new object());
        }
This one refuses due to the params?

Comment: @stian: Well what is the `new object()` part for? That's one oddity... the other is that you might just want `FromAsync(client.BeginSetGridLayout(gridLayout), client.EndSetGridLayout, null)`. Or if it *really* wants a `Func<IAsyncResult>`, you can use: `FromAsync(() => client.BeginSetGridLayout(gridLayout), client.EndSetGridLayout, null)`. (I haven't used `TaskFactory.FromAsync` much myself, but you should really look at the overloads available and work out which one you're trying to use, and consider the parameters in detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet The overload that takes a delegate to the `Begin` method is more efficient than the one that takes its resulting `IAsyncResult`, as mentioned by Stephen Toub at the end of his article [*Tasks and the APM Pattern*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx).

Comment: @JonSkeet; The last new object() is something I've pulled from traditional 3.5 WCF event driven async pattern. Basically for preventing multiple delegates to fire when hooked on a completion event. You probably don't need that here. Cheers to both of you :)